# Class abstract or not

Tags: methods

com.sun.mirror.type.TypeMirror

I am getting the return type of method as above is there anyway I can find out if it is abstract or not ?

Answer (score 1):

I googled the class name and found [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/mirror/com/sun/mirror/type/TypeMirror.html). It's an interface.